# Why is Firefox rendering images larger than Chrome or Safari?

Tags: html, cross-browser

I have the following markup on a webpage (uses Twitter Bootstrap)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span2">
    <a href="xxxx" class="link">
      <img src="path/to/image1.png">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="span2">
    <a href="xxxx" class="link">
      <img src="path/to/image2.png">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="span2">
    <a href="xxxx" class="link">
      <img src="path/to/image3.png">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="span2">
    <a href="xxxx" class="link">
      <img src="path/to/image4.png">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

#css

.link img {max-width: 100% }
```

In Chrome and Safari this is being rendered as expected.

In Firefox the images are much larger!

Why would Firefox render this differently?

Answer (score 1):

Check your zoom settings. You can reset the Firefox zoom with `Ctrl-0`.

Comment: i don't think its zoom. The rest of the page is correct, only these images are rendered at 4x size

Comment: Post a screeenshot. Firefox (and other browsers) let the user set image size independent of text size.